# Why does this not compile?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, polymorphism

Coming from Java or Python I am used to making such constructs and normally it "just works". Been discovering C# lately and, other than a few frustrations, find it quite pleasant to work with.

One such frustration is how much I have to hold it's hands through polymorphism constructs (override, virtual, etc).

Here is one such case I have not yet found how to "just make work".

```
class Polymorphism
{
    public interface IPerson
    {
        String Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Doctor : IPerson
    {
        public String Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class DoctorGroup
    {
        public IEnumerable<IPerson> Members
        {
            get
            {
                return DoctorMembers;
            }
        }

        public List<Doctor> DoctorMembers { get; set; }
        public DoctorGroup()
        {
            DoctorMembers = new List<Doctor>();
        }
    }
}
```

Here the `DoctorMembers` are `IPerson`s, thus I should be able to just return a list of doctors when asked for an `IEnumerable` of `IPerson`.

```
public IEnumerable<IPerson> Members
{
    get
    {
        return DoctorMembers;
    }
}
```

Yet...   the compiler complains... why? What am I missing? Semantically there is nothing wrong with this, most OOP languages I have worked with thus far can digest this without syntactic Pepto-Bismol. Am I missing a keyword to make it obvious to the compiler?

The obvious shortcut here is to LINQ convert all the doctors to `IPerson` but I fail to see why this is necessary or even desirable.

Anybody can light my lantern?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This code *does* compile with C# 4 targeting .NET 4, but wouldn't have compiled in C# 3, which didn't have [*generic variance*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233059.aspx).

Basically you want an implicit conversion from `IEnumerable<Doctor>` to `IEnumerable<IPerson>`. That's safe, because you can only get values "out" of an `IEnumerable<T>`... which is why in .NET 4, it's declared as `IEnumerable<out T>`.

Read more on generic variance for details, and remember that this is only available in C# 4 and upwards.

(If you *have* to use C# 3 or .NET 3.5, you can use the solution shown by CSharpie... but ideally, upgrade to a more recent version :)

Comment: Thanks Jon, indeed it does work once I ensured C#4.  However it seems that not all generics have been moved to such constructs.  For example  if I used IOrderedEnumerable in the group of IPerson and performed a Linq OrderBy before returning the doctors I get back to the compile error I had... even in C#4.  That said...  using IEnnumerable here is clearly the lesser of two "evils"!

Comment: @Newtopian That's because variance is tricky and not all such conversions (even some which appear "obviously" correct) are safe. Read up on co-, contra- and non-variance and look at some examples (such as why [array covariance is wrong](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance_%28computer_science%29#Arrays_in_C.23_and_Java)).

Comment: @Newtopian: Yes, `IOrderedEnumerable<T>` isn't covariant - see the documentation. It's not immediately clear to me if it *could* be - I suspect not due to the `CreateOrderedEnumerable` method.

Comment: @delnan I almost never use arrays because of the corner cases they have, being rarely bound by performace requirements I have that luxury.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Thanks, I'll have to dig deeper in *variance, I guess my shortcomming in this case is more of the theoratical nature than missing syntax elements.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
public IEnumerable<IPerson> Members
{
    get
    {
        return DoctorMembers.Cast<IPerson>();
    }
}
```

Comment: This was already mentioned and summarily dismissed by the OP.

Comment: My reply was first. but Jon Skeet's version was way better in detail, I admit ^^

Comment: yes, this is what I did hoping I would find a way to do this without casting.  I try and stay away from casting anything.  I usually interpret casting as an architecture code smell.